# муссировать этимология

Tags: этимология

муссировать этимология please inform

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F&l=1

Answer (score 4):

Французские слова mousse - пена, mousser - вспенивать. В русском глагол используется в переносном значении "раздувать важность" (события, дела).